# Are my HD failures caused by a SATA port issue or is the hard drive just failing?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart

I'm currently trying to figure out whether a new HD that I purchased a few weeks back is faulty or if it's a problem with the SATA port (if that's even possible).

Issue started on bootup, BIOS screen showed the HD had a SMART failure and I should replace it. I started copying files off it and after several minutes of copying files (using rsync), the copies would start failing and the drive / files would become inaccessible. I should note that the entire drive partition is mounted using Veracrypt so the files would remain inaccessible until I unmounted the partition in Veracrypt and remounted it, then the files were accessible again.

This same behaviour would repeat with the disconnect becoming more frequent - I assumed this was just the drive deteriorating.

I ran an extended SMART test against the drive and everything appears to be showing OK:

[image]

This made me wonder if it was really the hard drive that was the problem. My previous two disks have also failed (I believe on the same HD port but they've lasted a few years at least) and exhibited the exact same behaviour - they would give a SMART error, work a bit but start disconnecting and then eventually not mount at all.

I've now changed the port and cable that the HD is using and so far have been able to copy ~130gb off it. I'll continue copying files off it to see if it has the same issue but is there any way I can be sure that it won't start failing again and that the issue is with the HD since if there's a problem with the drive, I'd like to get it replaced now within the returns window.

Update: Copying off it appeared fine. Copying to it appeared to be going fine until I tried to browse the drive in file explorer which wouldn't show any files (and doing an "ls" in bash gave an "input / output error") even though Rsync was still copying to it. I stopped the Rsync copy and found that the mount point had changed - it was initially on /dev/sdd but was now at /dev/sdf - I'm assuming it had become unmounted and was remounted automatically but I don't know enough about this to say.

So given it's still showing issues, is it fair to say it's just a drive issue, even though SMART appears to be passing?

Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide.

Comment: Connect another known good drive.  My previous main computer, which I had for years was intermittently having all kinds of random disk problems.  Turns out the SATA controller was going bad.  Also, test that drive in another computer, if possible.

Comment: what brand drive is this? it sometimes help interpret RAW SMART values.

Comment: @Keltari - thank you, I'll try a different SATA Controller. I'm afraid I can't test the drive in a different computer at the moment but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen It's a Seagate Exos X18 Enterprise Class, Internal Hard Drive HDD, CMR 3,5", Hyperscale SATA 6 Gb/s, 7.200 RPM, 512e, 4 KB FastFormat, with cache, (ST18000NM000J).

Answer (score 0):

The SMART attributes values hint at that it is an interface error.

- Disk platters are probably fine (0 pending relocation, 0 relocated, 0 bad), and the drive is supposedly had seen only a week of use (power-on hours) and had only experienced 43 power-ons, so it is basically "new".
- UDMA CRC errors mean that cable or port was bad, or something else at the interface level. It could be bad SATA controller in the motherboard or controller in the device, too. But such problems are *rare*. They often manifest themselves in *overheating* of some components; SATA controller is often built into motherboard "south bridge", look for a large chip near SATA ports, sometimes it has a heatsink. Try touching it, it shouldn't be *too* hot. Try attaching a fan to it and see if it solves the problem.
- More often, problems are caused by *bad power*. Check your PSU; does it deliver the expected power, or its voltages sometimes drift outside of allowed range (±5%, e.g. 12V must be within 11.4V to 12.6V, and so on). Sometimes motherboard has sensors that can be used from the OS to monitor PSU voltages. Try using `sensors` program from [lm_sensors project](https://hwmon.wiki.kernel.org/lm_sensors); there should be GUIs for that, but I never tried them.

Answer (score 0):

Normalised values for SMART variables start at the values of 100 or 200
and go down for errors until they reach the Threshold, when the
firmware will sound the alarm.

The strange fact with your SMART data is that you have had
"Read Error Rate" and "Seek Error Rate" but nothing else,
especially no write errors which one would expect from a bad disk.

It seems that the disk encounters no problems with writing the data,
once the command to do so reaches the firmware.
However, reaching the disk for reading sometimes encounters errors,
which are apparently not hard errors.

I would guess that this is a communication error between the computer
and the disk. I would suggest to check the SATA cable, or try another
one of high quality. Check all contacts and also whether the cable is
well shielded.

I note that anything we can say from here would only be a guess.
If you're unsure, ask a professional for checkup.

Comment: FWIW the read error rates and seek error rates in this case account for *zero* errors.